# Closing MySQL Database Connections and Instances

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have three consecutive php files, One that shows results from a database fetch query, One that inserts data into the database and One that updates data. The first php file goes to the second and the second goes to the third. They all share the same database connection and database. In the first one I write   `$db = Database::getInstance();
  $mysqli = $db->getConnection();` Should I close the database connection with `mysqli_close($mysqli);` on every file??? I think it should be closed on the third file only. Let me know.

Comment: If you are including these using the "include" function, you only have to do it once - wether that is at the end of your third file, or below all of the includes in the first, is up to you.

Comment: declare a function with mysqli_close() in first file, then call the function when you need...

Comment: @MarceloAymone mysql_close() is already a function, why the need to wrap it into another one? Also, IIRC unless you're trying to free a lot of memory you don't even need to close the connection manually, it's done automatically

Comment: You are not required to explicitly call `mysqli_close()`, it will happen automatically once your database object goes out of scope at the end of your script.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, you're right, but only if the connection is not persistent, and in most cases it is not.